# virtual environment approach for packages

Tags: pythonpath, virtual-environment

I'm starting to use virtual environments.  I'm a little unclear on how to efficiently work with them and globally installed packages.  For example, if I want to use Numpy in my project within a virtual environment, does it make sense to install Numpy into the environment for the project?  I'm assuming no, since I will then have to install Numpy many times for different projects.  So maybe I need to set environment $PYTHONPATH for each project?  Is it correct that there should be a separate $PYTHONPATH variable for each project?  Or is there some other way to manage this correctly?  Thanks for any recommendations you may have to offer.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have personally adopted the habit of making a virtual environment (venv) for each significant project, plus a default venv in my home directory. This might help you also. Python venvs are cheap!

I name each venv the same as my python project.

Bonus tip: Imagine a project called `blah`, then there would also be a venv at `~/venvs/blah`. A bash alias could be defined called `blah` that activates the venv and cds into the project directory:

```sh
alias blah="source ~/.venv/blah/bin/activate; cd ~/work/blah"
```

Now you type `blah` at a shell prompt and you are working on that project. Boom!

Comment: Thanks Mike -- I like the consistency and efficiency of your approach.  To further your example:  If I have Numpy installed on my system, and I want to use it in blah, how do I do that?  It should be a specific Numpy version for blah, in case sometime in the future I update Numpy, but want to keep the original version of Numpy for blah.  I am missing the detail of how this works, such that blah can find it's version of Numpy, separately from all other projects with their own venvs.

Comment: I used to create a `requirements.txt` file and use the `-r` argument for pip to install all dependencies. Recently I started creating a `requirements.in` file and using `pip-tools`. I wrote a blog about it https://www.mslinn.com/blog/2021/04/05/pip-tools.html